# How to add new columns to dataframe with value taken from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:
df1.head():

```
    nazwa województwa   gmina nazwa gminy  rodzaj gminy
0  Zachodniopomorskie  320101   Białogard             1
1  Zachodniopomorskie  320101   Białogard             1
2  Zachodniopomorskie  320101   Białogard             1
3  Zachodniopomorskie  320101   Białogard             1
4  Zachodniopomorskie  320101   Białogard             1
```

and kts_df.head():

```
               name         type        KTS_code TERYT_code
0            Polska      COUNTRY  10000000000000       None
1           Bochnia  RURAL_GMINA  10011212001022    1201022
2           Drwinia  RURAL_GMINA  10011212001032    1201032
3         Iwanowice  RURAL_GMINA  10011212006032    1206032
4  Lipnica Murowana  RURAL_GMINA  10011212001042    1201042
```

Currently to add new column to df1 I am using

`df['kts'] = df.apply(lambda row: self.get_kts_code(row, kts_df), axis=1)`
where

```
    def get_kts_code(self, row, kts_df: DataFrame) -> str:
            """Get the KTS code of each miasto/wieś."""
            gmina_types = {
                '1': AdministrativeUnitType.URBAN_GMINA,
                '2': AdministrativeUnitType.RURAL_GMINA,
                '4': AdministrativeUnitType.MIXED_GMINA,
                '5': AdministrativeUnitType.RURAL_AREA,
                '8': AdministrativeUnitType.DISTRICT,
                '9': AdministrativeUnitType.DELEGATION,
            }
            nazwa_gminy = row['nazwa gminy']
            gmina_type = gmina_types[str(row['rodzaj gminy'])]
            teryt = kts_df['TERYT_code'].str.contains(str(row['gmina']))
            kts_code = kts_df.loc[
                (kts_df['name'] == nazwa_gminy) & (kts_df['type'] == gmina_type) & (teryt)
            ]
            kts_code = kts_code['KTS_code'].values[0]
            return kts_code
```

This code works well, but to process df1 with about 200k rows it takes about an hour, too slow. Probably there can be another way to quickly find correct kts_code from kts_df for each row of df1?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have trouble understanding what you are doing. What I suggest is that you use pd.merge() function on both dataframes, after you have built the appropriate join column in both

Comment: right. I had to use merge with setting multiple columns to `left_on` and `right_on` parameters. And it seems to be working. Testing it now. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've got your demand right, but you could try the following:

- create a df with the corresponding gmina_type mapping
- join kts_df with gmina_types_df to get the gmina IDs
- join df1 with the enriched kts_df

Code Example:

```
gmina_types = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'type': ['URBAN_GMINA', 'RURAL_GMINA', 'MIXED_GMINA', 'RURAL_AREA', 'DISTRICT']
}

gmina_types_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gmina_types)

kts_df = kts_df.join(gmina_types_df.set_index('type'), on='type')
df1 = df1.join(kts_df.set_index('id'), on='rodzaj gminy')
```

Comment: Thanks this approach lead me to read docs about dataframes joining and merging. After some time trying - I found the solution that I needed. It gave me incredible time saving.